# Finding correlation of two data frames using python

Tags: python, correlation

I am working on a data set and after performing the bucketing operation over two columns, I ended up with two buckets that have maximum number of data points.

For those two buckets, I have created two separate data frames, which is of different shapes (number of columns are same and the number of rows are different) so as to compare them.

I need to know which transformation I can use to perform a correlation of two data frames possible. How can I do that?

Any other suggestions for comparing data frames are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bin them both to vectors of equal length, with bin or window sizes dependent on the shapes of the input frames, then calculate correlation on the vectors.

Comment: First you have to make both data frames of same size. Coz, that&amp;#39;s where you will be able to find which variables are correlated.>>>df2.corrwith(df1.Y)

Where df2 , df1 are data frames.